# simple explanation of the State software design pattern.

Tags: design-patterns

I understand the idea of changing states, what I don't understand is what it means on wikipedia when it says that this pattern allows the object to

> partially change its type at runtime
>   How exactly is this done? The wiki is a little vague on the concepts.

Comment: I recommend skipping wikipedia and going straight to your copy of "Design Patterns".  And if you don't own it then rectify that ASAP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of the State Pattern is that in some Context class some behavior is defined in another object.

```
public class Context
{
    ....

    public void Request()
    {
       _state.Handle(this);
    }
}
```

The behavior of `Request` depends on the current value of `_state`. `State` is something that can change at run time and for the user of `Context`, the behavior of `Context` will change.

In the following code the current `Context` is passed to the `State` and the `State` can change the `Context`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The 'State' abstract class
    /// </summary>
    abstract class State
    {
        public abstract void Handle(Context context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A 'ConcreteState' class
    /// </summary>
    class ConcreteStateA : State
    {
        public override void Handle(Context context)
        {
            context.State = new ConcreteStateB();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A 'ConcreteState' class
    /// </summary>
    class ConcreteStateB : State
    {
        public override void Handle(Context context)
        {
            context.State = new ConcreteStateA();
        }
    }
```

This example is taken from [dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx#_self1%5C) which contains a description of most popular design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is meant by that statement is that you can have a single object of class Cursor (to borrow wikipedia's example), and use it as a tool.

However, the internal state of the Cursor object can either be a PenTool or a SelectionTool, and it can switch back and forth without affecting Cursor object. So, in essence, Cursor object, when used as a tool, "changes its type" from PenTool to SelectionTool and back without affecting code that is using the Cursor object.